# Minitoc Chapter and Title on Same Line and Centered. Center TOC, also

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book} % [text size]{document type}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext} %for testing
\usepackage{minitoc} % Get chapter level TOC
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\dominitoc
\setcounter{parttocdepth}{4} % set minitoc sublevel
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % to get X.X.X.X
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}

\begin{document}

\chapter{SAMPLE CHAPTER }\label{ch5}

\minitoc{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\section{My Section 1}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 1}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 2}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{My Section  1 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}
\section{My Section 2}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 1}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 2}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

So how do I get "Chapter 1 SAMPLE CHAPTER" on the same line and centered?  I also need to center the Table of Contents and adjust the vertical spacing.
Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully solve this.  But I was able to get the Chapter Number and Chapter Title on the same line.  Here's a MWE for it:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book} % [text size]{document type}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, blindtext} %for testing
\usepackage{minitoc} % Get chapter level TOC
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\mtctitle}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\dominitoc
\setcounter{parttocdepth}{4} % set minitoc sublevel
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % to get X.X.X.X
\mtcsetrules{*}{off}
\titleformat{\chapter} {\large\bfseries}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{0em}{---}
\titleformat{\section} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{0em}{---}
\titleformat{\subsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0em}{---}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0em}{---}
\begin{document}

\chapter{SAMPLE CHAPTER }\label{ch5}

\minitoc{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\newpage
\section{My Section 1}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 1}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 2}
\subsection{My Section  1 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{My Section  1 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}
\section{My Section 2}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 1}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 2}
\subsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{My Section  2 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}
\newpage


\chapter{Next CHAPTER }\label{ch6}

\minitoc{\protect\thispagestyle{fancy}}

\section{New Section 1}
\subsection{New Section  1 Subsection 1}
\subsection{New Section  1 Subsection 2}
\subsection{New Section  1 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{New Section  1 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}
\section{New Section 2}
\subsection{New Section  2 Subsection 1}
\subsection{New Section  2 Subsection 2}
\subsection{New Section  2 Subsection 3}
\subsubsection{New Section  2 Subsection 3  Subsubsection 1}


\end{document}
```

And that gets this done:
[image]